# Run a single test in Pycharm by selecting the test in Editor

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I use pycharm as editor for RobotFramework and I'm trying to run a single test by selecting the test instead of using Terminal.
I have installed IntellibotPatched.
I have followed several guidelines like this one
http://ha-phan.vn/rfw5-configure-pycharm-intellij-ide-to-run-robot-frameworks-testsuite-testcase/?unapproved=644171&moderation-hash=49c0d867cc4d9919ef23a6a45dad1f31#comment-644171
to run my test, but on the Run terminal of pycharm, it doesn't recognize the testcase that i select.
inside my External tool in the argument field i have added this line
`-t "$Tests$" $FileDir$\$FileName$` but when i select the test case in editor and right clik then choose my external tool, it doesn't recognize the :    "$Tests$"    variable.
My selection of the name of the file on the editor, should replace this variable in the quote but it doesn't.
thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-t "$Tests$" $FileDir$\$FileName$`  should be written like below

`-t "$SelectedText$" -A "cred.txt" $FileName$` in Argument Section

`$FileDir$`  in Working Directory Section

[image: Sample Screenshot For External Files]

Comment: Thank you. i first copied your arguments in mine and ran it on my .robot file. It worked in the sense that it executed it in Python.  Then i removed the -A parameter on the argument, and this time it ran it in Robot. at the end I changed the absolute address you mentioned in your argument with the $FileDir$\$FileName$ as i had before and it still works.